# Very few supported devices of my Flutter app on PlayConsole

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Its been a very fun adventure with Flutter so far and my app just got published in PlayStore but I have 2 problems

1. Its not visible on most devices
2. The supported devices is VERY FEW (25 only)

How do I increase the supported versions of Androids? Like from Jellybean to latest?

> Its an ALPHA RELEASE

below is the image for reference

[image: Only supported devices]

my **APP-LEVEL build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hivemanila.syncshop_webview"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: what is the install count for your alpha app? May be only the released app will be checked for all the available devices.

Comment: None yet. Ive set 2 emails for internal testing of the alpha and I cant still view it on PlayStore :(

Comment: I still think that the supported device count will update once your app is released at least as a beta version.

Comment: Doesnt it have something to do with the build gradle?

Comment: I don't think so, because as per the build.gradle file, your app should be supported for all devices from API 16 to 28

Comment: question, what is the equivalent of minSdkVersion 16 and targetedSdkVersion 28? Im new to app development and still have a lot to learn tbh.

Comment: API - 16 Jelly bean, API 28 - Oreo. [Full list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history).

Comment: Thanks. So I think its just the state of the app right now which is Alpha, right? I cant open it on any phones but when I get the opt-link from PlayConsole I cvan view it but I have to Pre Register

Comment: I am not much experienced with hiw playstore listing works at all. I am just assuming the above as The company I work for has a flutter app listed and the build.gradle is same as yours but supported devices are  12-13k

Comment: Okay thanks! Can you. Upvote this so it will go up ? I cant seem to find any additional info regarding this...

Comment: I think that you have a problem with native code processor architecture, which is probably x86-only in your case (you need ARM and ARM_64 too). I can't see the full devices list on your shot, but 2 visible devices are x86-based, that's why I suspect this issue. May be you released an APK built for your desktop Emulator?

Comment: Can you share your `AndroidManifest` file? Please exclude any sensitive info by using dummy strings/values. What's the file size of your APK?